# I need to grant every privilege to my local database user

Tags: oracle, database-administration

I need the ability to create anything and need to have the debug privilege especially.

I have a Oracle database in my home and I want to run its export script against my work PC database but I don't want to use the **system** user.

I have tried `grant connect,resource,dba to myuser;` but I still could not create a view!

Comment: The (deprecated) `resource` privilege will certainly give you the rights to create a view. There must be something you are not telling us. What is the exact error message you get? Did you try to disconnect and connect again using `myuser`after granting the privileges?

Comment: A want to give user priv as the full system and sysdba any way thi is a self answer question for me and everyone future reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a short paper showing how to grant "all privileges" to a user in Oracle and more importantly what privileges are needed to do this. This was a posting I made to one of the newsgroups/mailing lists recently. This is for information only as it is useful to know BUT one important fact that should be highlighted here is that i cannot think of any circumstances or when ALL PRIVILEGES should be granted to anyone. It is simply unnecessary. Do the job correctly and find out the exact privileges needed for the job in hand and grant those. Granting all privileges is a security risk as it means the user having those privileges can do just about anything in your database.

Remember use least privilege principle at all times and grant what is needed. Do not grant everything just to get the job done quickly. Here is the example code!

```
Connected to:
    Personal Oracle9i Release 9.2.0.1.0 - Production
    With the Partitioning, OLAP and Oracle Data Mining options
    JServer Release 9.2.0.1.0 - Production

    SQL> 
    SQL> sho user
    USER is "SYSTEM"
    SQL> select * from system_privilege_map
      2  where name like '%PRIV%';

     PRIVILEGE NAME                                       PROPERTY
    ---------- ---------------------------------------- ----------
          -167 GRANT ANY PRIVILEGE                               0
          -244 GRANT ANY OBJECT PRIVILEGE                        0

    SQL> 
    SQL> -- Create a new user with just create session (to log on) and grant 
    SQL> -- any privilege to, well grant all privileges.
    SQL> create user emil identified by emil;

    User created.

    SQL> grant create session, grant any privilege to emil;

    Grant succeeded.

    SQL> -- because we want to test this privilege create a second user to 
    SQL> -- test it with
    SQL> create user zulia identified by zulia;

    User created.

    SQL> -- connect as emil and grant all privileges to Zulia
    SQL> connect emil/emil@sans
    Connected.
    SQL> grant all privileges to zulia;

    Grant succeeded.

    SQL> -- connect as system and find out if it worked.
    SQL> connect system/manager@sans
    Connected.

    SQL> select count(*),grantee
      2  from dba_sys_privs
      3  where grantee in ('MDSYS','EMIL','ZULIA')
      4* group by grantee
    SQL> /

      COUNT(*) GRANTEE
    ---------- ------------------------------
             2 EMIL
           139 MDSYS
           139 ZULIA

    SQL>
```

We used `MDSYS` as a checkpoint as `MDSYS` has all privileges granted to it
    by default in a default installation of Oracle. The privilege you need
    therefore is `GRANT ANY PRIVILEGE`

Comment: He asked for privileges on local development system, there the security issue should be less critical.